# How to put color significance legend in Javascript infovis jit library

Tags: javascript, jit, infovis

i am using Jit.js for tree map.

How i can put color significance legend in jit.js and color of box should be appear according to values basis define in each node.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Thanx for your reply...Actually i have one tree map and  inside each node i m display different values.so i want to put legend and inside the legend i want to  paas 3 color range if value is less than 50 than show each node red and if value between 50 to 80 than yellow and if value is greater than 80 than green and corresponding color will be display inside each node of tree map..plz tell me how i can do that